# interact with SAP systems via ruby web app

Tags: ruby, web-applications, saprfc

I have a Hanami web app which interacts with SAP systems via VB scripts.

Is there an alternative way for Ruby which would enable the same level of interaction, i.e. connect to a system and perform some actions to either post or retrieve data from a system?

I've read about RFC and web services, but it seems they're no longer supported for Ruby. Or am I wrong?

EDIT------------------------

I currently have a web and a desktop app that basically do the same thing. Trigger the execution of a VBS file as shown below:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3("cscript.exe //Nologo path/to/some_vbs_file.vbs #{@param1} #{@param2} #{@param3})
```

This way I get the data into the VBS and pipe it out as well.

However I've been looking for an alternate way, like mentioned here:
[Ruby, Ruby on Rails, and SAP Web Services Integration](http://www.piersharding.com/blog/archives/2006/10/ruby_ruby_on_ra.html)

But some of the libs on ruby-lang.org are no longer accessible and the entire project is a bit outdated. So I wanted to ask if someone can advise where to look for an alternative, if any.

Thank you.

seba

Comment: Hanami is build on Ruby. If you have an existing Hanami app that is able to interact with SAP, then this can certainly done in plain Ruby too. Can you provide more information: What gems do you use, how does the code look like, do you have any documentation on the interface? What have you tried so far? What problem do you face?

Comment: @spickermann please see my edited question.

Comment: Seems like you just need an up-to-date [SOAP client](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/soap).